# How do I create an in-memory handle in Haskell?

Tags: file-io, haskell, io

I want something that looks like a file handle but is really backed by an in-memory buffer to use for I/O redirects. How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to  revisit this question, there's a new answer that you should see.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen It seems that John's answer is exactly what you want.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's not possible without modifying the compiler.  This is because Handle is an abstract data type, not a typeclass.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I really just wanted to know if there was an idiomatic Haskell way to do this that I didn't know of, so this answer sues me.

Answer (score 21):

I just wrote a library which provides this, called "knob" [[hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/knob)]. You can use it to create `Handle`s which reference/modify a `ByteString`:

```
import Data.ByteString (pack)
import Data.Knob
import System.IO

main = do
    knob <- newKnob (pack [])
    h <- newFileHandle knob "test.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn h "Hello world!"
    hClose h
    bytes <- Data.Knob.getContents knob
    putStrLn ("Wrote bytes: " ++ show bytes)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can express what you want to do in terms of C or system calls you could use Haskell's Foreign Function Interface (FFI).  I started to suggest using mmap, but on second thought I think mmap might be a mapping the wrong way even if you used it with the anonymous option.

You can find more information about the Haskell FFI at the haskell.org wiki.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug in the library design, and one that's annoyed me, too. I see two approaches to doing what you want, neither of which is terribly attractive.

1. Create a new typeclass, make the current handle an instance of it, write another instance to do the in-memory-data thing, and change all of your programs that need to use this facility. Possibly this is as simple as importing `System.SIO` (or whatever you want to call it) instead of `System.IO`. But if you use the custom I/O routines in libraries such as `Data.ByteString`, there's more work to be done there.
2. Rewrite the I/O libraries to extend them to support this. Not trivial, and a lot of work, but it wouldn't be particularly difficult work to do. However, then you've got a compatibility issue with systems that don't have this library.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible. [GHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler), at least, seems to require a handle to have an OS file descriptor that is used for all read/write/seek operations.

See `/libraries/base/IOBase.lhs` from the GHC sources.

You may be able to get the same effect by enlisting the OS's help: create a temporary file, connect the handle to it and then memory map the file for the I/O redirects. This way, all the handle I/O would become visible in the memory mapped section.

Answer (score 1):

To add a modern answer to this question, you could use `createPipe` from `System.Process`:

```
createPipe :: IO (Handle, Handle)
```

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.3/process-1.6.1.0/System-Process.html#v:createPipe

Comment: The docs for `createPipe` say "*Create a pipe for interprocess communication [...]*". How does this solve OP's question?